# SQLAlchemy - list data from two tables with one query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new in Flask and Sqlalchemy and I struggle to find some solution where I can get data from two tables in SQLAlchemy with one query

For example if I have two tables:

```
table A                               table B
-------------------------             --------------------
id   |  value | name                 id   |   pass   |   name
 1   |  10    | first_name            1   |    no    |   first_name
 2   |  20    | second_name           2   |    yes   |   second_name
```

Is there a query where I can filter both of the tables by name, for example "first_name" and get something like this:

```
<A 1>
<B 1>
```

I tried with .join, but I'm getting this output, if there are more records with the same name:

```
[<A1> <B1>]
[<A3> <B1>]
[<A1> <B3>]
[<A3> <B3>]etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all results from each table that match certain conditions, you can use `UNION`

```
SELECT 'A' as tablename, id FROM A WHERE name='first name'
UNION
SELECT 'B' as tablename, id FROM B WHERE name='first name'
```

Comment: The relevant SQLALchemy [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=union#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.union)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is indeed what I need, but after using union I get message

"All selectables passed to CompoundSelect must have identical numbers of columns; select #1 has 8 columns, select #2 has 7"

Can UNION be used for tables with different number of columns ?

Comment: I just filtered the Queue's for the two columns I need using .with_entities and I get my desired result :D